# Using Moebius Inversion to solve a functional equation.

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I am reading about Moebius inversions, and I am given the following claim:

$\sum_{d=1}^{\infty} f(z^d) = g(z)$ with $g(z) = O(z)$ at $z=0$, implies that $f(z) = \sum_{d=1}^{\infty} \mu(d)g(z^d)$ by directly applying the Moebius inversion to the relationship on the coefficients.

The relationship I see on the coefficients is $g_n = \sum_{d|n} f_d$, but if I apply the Moebius inversion relation, I would get that $f_n = \sum_{d|n} g_d\mu(n/d)$

I don't see how to get the result from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your coefficient relation

$$f_n = \sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d) g_{n/d}.$$

Then multiply with $z^n$:

$$f_n z^n = \sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d) g_{n/d}(z^d)^{n/d}$$

and sum:

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n z^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d) g_{n/d}(z^d)^{n/d} = \sum_{d=1}^\infty \mu(d)\sum_{d\mid n} g_{n/d}(z^d)^{n/d} = \sum_{d=1}^\infty \mu(d)g(z^d).$$

Comment: Yes, or all $n$ of the form $k\cdot d$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$. We sum over all pairs $(n,d)$ with $d\mid n$, and switch the order of summation.